# Plot generalized linear mixed models (GLMMs): mixture of categorical and numeric variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models

I'd like to plot the relationship between the number of `ladenant` response variable in function of `Bioma` (categorical) and `temp` (numeric) using binomial negative
generalized linear mixed models (GLMMs) without success. I try to do:

```
#Packages
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

#Open my dataset
myds<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_glmm_dataset.csv")
myds <- myds[,-c(3)] # remove bad character variable

# Negative binomial GLMM
m.laden.1  <- glmer.nb(ladenant ~ Bioma +  poly(temp,2) + scale(UR) + (1 | formigueiro), data = DataBase)

# Plot the results
mydf <- ggpredict(m.laden.1, terms = c("temp","Bioma"))
ggplot(mydf, aes(x, predicted), group = Bioma) +
  geom_point(DataBase, aes(temp, ladenant), alpha = 0.5) + # Observed ladenant response variable
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = .1)
```

I have a not so good plot because I don't have one line for each `Bioma` and bad lines for `temp` variable:

[image: my-plot]

But the object `mydf` specification contains the `Bioma` variable:

```
mydf 

# # Predicted counts of ladenant

# # Bioma = Atlantic Forest

# temp | Predicted |         95% CI
# ---------------------------------
#   10 |      1.88 | [ 0.81,  4.35]
#   15 |     12.95 | [ 9.11, 18.40]
#   20 |     32.61 | [26.42, 40.25]
#   25 |     30.00 | [23.51, 38.28]
#   30 |     10.08 | [ 4.79, 21.24]
#   35 |      1.24 | [ 0.24,  6.43]

# # Bioma = Transition

# temp | Predicted |          95% CI
# ----------------------------------
#   10 |      6.84 | [ 3.04,  15.42]
#   15 |     47.17 | [34.05,  65.34]
#   20 |    118.79 | [92.27, 152.94]
#   25 |    109.29 | [76.84, 155.43]
#   30 |     36.73 | [16.17,  83.44]
#   35 |      4.51 | [ 0.82,  24.71]

# # Bioma = Pampa

# temp | Predicted |         95% CI
# ---------------------------------
#   10 |      1.42 | [ 0.70,  2.90]
#   15 |      9.80 | [ 7.47, 12.86]
#   20 |     24.69 | [18.74, 32.52]
#   25 |     22.71 | [16.46, 31.35]
#   30 |      7.63 | [ 3.65, 15.96]
#   35 |      0.94 | [ 0.19,  4.67]

# Adjusted for:
# *          UR = 82.78
# * formigueiro = 0 (population-level)
```

Plaese, any help to improve this plot?

Comment: I think you need to use ``group = Bioma``.

Comment: Can you remove the bad characters `"1�"` from your data? Also, you have data sets `myds` and `mydf` but `geom_point` refers to `DataBase`.

Comment: I edit the question changing `color` by `group` and remove the column with bad character (`myds <- myds[,-c(3)]`) but doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to be careful with the different names of the variables in the two objects `myds` and `mydf`, and where you place them in the calls to the various `geom`s:

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

#Open my dataset
myds<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_glmm_dataset.csv")
myds <- myds[,-c(3)] # remove bad character variable

# Negative binomial GLMM
m.laden.1 <- glmer.nb(ladenant ~ Bioma +  poly(temp,2) + scale(UR) + (1 | formigueiro),
                      data = myds)

# Plot the results
mydf <- ggpredict(m.laden.1, terms = c("temp [all]", "Bioma"))

ggplot(mydf, aes(x, predicted)) +
  geom_point(data=myds, aes(temp, ladenant, color = Bioma), alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
  labs(x = "temp", y = "ladenant")
```

[image]

Note that I haven't included your `geom_ribbon`, because the `conf.low` and `conf.high` are all `NA` in the upper half of the curve, which makes it look pretty messy.

Incidentally, the plot might be more informative with a log y scale:

```r
ggplot(mydf, aes(x, predicted)) +
  geom_point(data=myds, aes(temp, ladenant, color = Bioma), alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  labs(x = "temp", y = "ladenant")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `plot()`, which returns a ggplot object, and add additional layers as needed.

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

#Open my dataset
myds<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_glmm_dataset.csv")
myds <- myds[,-c(3)] # remove bad character variable

# Negative binomial GLMM
m.laden.1  <- glmer.nb(ladenant ~ Bioma +  poly(temp,2) + scale(UR) + (1 | formigueiro), data = myds)

mydf <- ggpredict(m.laden.1, terms = c("temp [all]","Bioma"))

plot(mydf, add.data = TRUE, ci = FALSE)
```

[image]

```r
plot(mydf, add.data = TRUE, ci = FALSE) + ggplot2::scale_y_log10()
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>